# From comp class algorithm time question, n=100 = 10 seconds with O(n^2) what is time with n=500

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o

An algorithm that is Θ(n^2) takes 10 seconds to execute n = 100. How long would when n = 500?

Answer = O(n2) is quadratic, n=100, 100^2 = 10000 = 10 seconds therefore, n=500, (5x100) ^2 = 250000 = 250 seconds

This seems reasonable but not sure.
Am I right or close.
Thank you

Comment: Such a question cannot be answered. This is not how Big O works. There may be constant terms, linear terms, logarithmic terms, all of which are not known because *O(n²)* hides all that information; You cannot simply derive by extrapolation a running time from time complexity. It might well be that for n=500, the running time is just 20 seconds. No-one can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you resolved the task you got in a "good way" (this was probably intended by teacher to do) - the task is trying to show how complexity affects input (in this example it shows that 5 times bigger input takes 25 times more time).

Altough it can help to understand why `O(n^2)` compare to `O(n)` is important to measure, the example is not correct.

This code is `O(n^2)`, but for `n=500` it takes `O(1)`

```
function ohNoHowComplexityWorks(n) {
  if (n == 500) {
    return 10;
  }
  for (i=0; i < n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
      // anything in constant time
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: trincot's comment is correct - you can't say that it will take 25 times as long for any fixed value of `n`, because big-O is an asymptotic result which ignores lower order terms.  Going from 100 to 500 might only take 10 times as long, or it might take 50 times as long, if there's a linear component which is subtractive or additive, respectively.

Comment: @pjs I agree with everything you and trincot have said, but all of that is moot when the question is posed by a professor who is unlikely to be receptive to the reply "there's not enough information" in lieu of the answer they were anticipating.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Speaking as a professor myself, I'd be thrilled if a student gave a good explanation of why there isn't an exact answer and could explain that *asymptotically* 5 times as much data should take 25 times as long for an O(n^2) process.

Comment: @pjs in my experience, your kind is the exception, not the rule, unfortunately.